# Import public key from github to local ubuntu account

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu (18.04) server and noticed during install that I could import public keys from github. I've now finished setup and would like to create some more users. It seems ideal to keep importing their public keys from github if possible. Is there a way to trigger that feature of importing keys from a public github profile for a user outside of the installation process?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A short while after posting the question I found the answer.  There is a special command `ssh-import-id` which can import ssh keys. The [man page for ssh-import-id](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssh-import-id.1.html) explains it quite well. It's hosted as [ssh-import-id on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ssh-import-id) as well.

Basic usage:

```
# import keys from github
ssh-import-id-gh <username>
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: This is such an easy way to use passwordless SSH auth, which is so much more secure and convenient than passwords. And this command works without issue on a raspberry pi as well.

Answer (score 12):

GitHub provides this via an [API Endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/) that you can download and parse. Unfortunately for us, this does return objects in a JSON format, so it's a bit hard to parse at times (especially in the shell).

Fortunately for us, there's another endpoint to get a user's public SSH keys:

```
https://github.com/<username>.keys
```

You can use this with `wget` to download and append keys really simply and without any parsing:

```
wget -O - https://github.com/myuser.keys >> /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note that in order to use this command, you will need write permissions to that user's homedir. You may optionally use `tee -a` as well, which would be easier if privileges aren't guaranteed:

```
wget -O - https://github.com/myuser.keys | sudo tee -a /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution. I found `ssh-import-id` which seems to do something similar into a command with some validation and error checking.

Comment: Confirmed this works with 20.04 server Installer Selected launchpad, instead of github, but this supports both.